# How to create image classes with background url CSS

Tags: html, css

I am making a game of chess and I want to create different classes that will display different background images.

For example, `<div class="pawn"></div>` should have a background image of a pawn. (A pawn is a chess piece). Here is what I have:

```
.king {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background:url(/imgs/pieces.png) 0px 0px;
}
.queen {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background:url(/imgs/pieces.png) 133.33333333333334px 0px;
}
```

Class king works although it is too large. But class queen does not appear. I measured the dimensions and the size of each piece is 133px. So am I using the `background` property correctly?

This is the sprite sheet I am using: [image: this]

Comment: You gotta add `px`. Try `background: url(/imgs/pieces.png) 133.33333333333334px 0;`

Comment: the duplicate will give a generic solution where you can easily define each pieces and alos scale them like you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to split your classes up, so your `.piece` class has all the common rules that every piece has, and restrict your "piece type" classes to just the `background-position-x` property. Then you can add a third class for black vs white pieces. I added style rules for the `.king` and `.white` classes, but since these both have the default background-x and y positions, they're not necessary.

```css
body {
  display: flex
}

body>div {
  border: solid 1px #333
}

.piece {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg/800px-Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg.png);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 467px auto;
}

.king {
  background-position-x: 0px;
}

.queen {
  background-position-x: -77px;
}

.white {
  background-position-y: 0px;
}

.black {
  background-position-y: -79px;
}
```

```html
<div class='piece king white'></div>
<div class='piece queen white'></div>
<div class='piece queen black'></div>
```